# WPF Button background and imagesource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button within a grid in WPF, and on a click of the button, the background should be replaced by a new image.  I have the code as follow:

```
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="1"  FontSize="100" Foreground="White" >
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding MyImgSource}" />
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

But my issue is, I want the background of the button to be black before the user goes and hit the button, so there will not be any image soruce feeding in until the user hits it.  So I am wondering is there anyway I can tell the button background to be black without supplying a black image as image source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to change the **Background** one time after user pressed the **Button**? If so you can use style with animations:

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonBackground.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background)" >
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <!--<SolidColorBrush Color="Pink"/>-->
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding MyImgSource}" />
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you want to return **Black** background to the **Button** after pressing then your style will be:

```
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <!--<SolidColorBrush Color="Pink"/>-->
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding MyImgSource}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```